# VSCode: "Go to definition" not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-code

I installed VSCode and found out that "Go to definition" not working.

It says "The definition for GetUsers not found" although GetUsers is defined in other module.
[image]
How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode doesn't have a notion of AngularJS's dependency injection, so it doesn't know where `usersService` is coming from and what it is (which properties and methods it contains), thus VSCode doesn't know anything about it.

There's nothing you can do as far as I know, it's simply a limitation of using AngularJS in VSCode.

The best work-around is to just search for the function in your workspace.