# VSCode "Go to definition" not working with dependency injection

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, dependency-injection

(tried looking for relevant answers .. [47092594](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092594/vscode-go-to-definition-not-working))

trying to implement some kind of dependency injection, and `VScode` can't recognize my functions/methods (`.methodA()`)

code for example :

```
function newServiceA({adapterA,adapterB}) {
  const service = {
    methodA() {
      return 1;
    },
  };
  return service;
}

const adapterA={...}
const adapterB = {...}

const serviceA = newServiceA({adapterA,adapterB});

function controller({ serviceA }) {
  serviceA.methodA(); // no definition .. seems like VSCode doesn't recognize it
}

controller({ serviceA });
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You're missing that what you want is impossible, not only in JavaScript. How could the IDE know, how this function will be called later at runtime without time machine? That's not a JavaScript problem. That's a dependency injection problem. You have the same problem with Java Spring and DI.

Comment: got it @jabaa, is there a way around it ? feels like I'm missing some key abilities I had before

Comment: No, it's a logical problem. DI adds a flexibility that doesn't allow it. You could call this function with different implementations. You could even add implementations at runtime.

Comment: Related: [How can I use "Go To Definition" for CommonJS `require`s in VS Code when the path to resolve is derived using runtime functions and values?](/q/75843679/11107541)